# Qlikview - join tables and update values

Tags: qlikview

I have QV report with table that looks like this:

```
+---------+--------+---------------+------+-------+
|  HOST   | OBJECT | SPECIFICATION | COPY | LAST  |
+---------+--------+---------------+------+-------+
| host001 | obj01  | spec01        | c1   | 15:55 |
| host002 | obj02  | spec02        | c2   | 14:30 |
| host003 | -      | -             | -    | -     |
| host004 | -      | -             | -    | -     |
+---------+--------+---------------+------+-------+
```

now I got another small table:

```
spec1
host1
host4
```

all I need is in loading script to connect these tables in this way:

the first row is specification and all others are hosts. If there is host with name from second row of second table(host1) and with specification from first row, than I need to copy all other values from the host row (host1) to rows where are other host from second table(host4), e.g.:

```
+---------+--------+---------------+------+-------+
|  HOST   | OBJECT | SPECIFICATION | COPY | LAST  |
+---------+--------+---------------+------+-------+
| host001 | obj01  | spec01        | c1   | 15:55 |
| host002 | obj02  | spec02        | c2   | 14:30 |
| host003 | -      | -             | -    | -     |
| host004 | obj01  | spec01        | c1   | 15:55 |
+---------+--------+---------------+------+-------+
```

I have several tables like the second one and I need to connect all of them. Sure, there can be multiple rows with same host, same specification, etc. in firts table. "-" sign is null() value and one can change the second table layout.

I tried all JOINS and now Im trying to iterate over whole table and comparing, but Im new to QV and Im missing some SQL features like UPDATE.

I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script, it's not perfect and there is probably a neater solution(!) but it works for your scenario.

I rearranged  your "Copy Table" so that it has three columns:

```
HOST      SPECIFICATION   TARGET_HOST
```

You could then repeat rows for the additional hosts that you wish to copy to as follows:

```
HOST      SPECIFICATION   TARGET_HOST
host001   spec01          host004
host001   spec01          host003
```

The script (I included some dummy data so you can try it out):

```
Source_Data:
LOAD * INLINE [
    HOST, OBJECT, SPECIFICATION, COPY, LAST
    host001, obj01, spec01  , c1, 15:55
    host002, obj02, spec02  , c2, 14:30
    host003
    host004
];

Copy_Table:
LOAD * INLINE [
    HOST, SPECIFICATION, TARGET_HOST
    host001, spec01, host004
];


Link_Table:
NOCONCATENATE
LOAD
    HOST & SPECIFICATION as %key,
    TARGET_HOST
RESIDENT Copy_Table;

DROP TABLE Copy_Table;

LEFT JOIN (Link_Table)
LOAD
    HOST & SPECIFICATION as %key,
    HOST, OBJECT, SPECIFICATION, COPY, LAST
    ;
LOAD
    *
RESIDENT Source_Data;


Complete_Data:
NOCONCATENATE LOAD
    TARGET_HOST as HOST,
    OBJECT, SPECIFICATION, COPY, LAST
RESIDENT Link_Table;

CONCATENATE (Complete_Data)
LOAD
    *
RESIDENT Source_Data 
WHERE NOT Exists(TARGET_HOST,HOST & SPECIFICATION);  // old condition: WHERE NOT Exists(TARGET_HOST,HOST);

DROP TABLES Source_Data, Link_Table;
```

Comment: Many thanks! Meanwhile I solved this problem with thousand of loops and joins, but this is really fast and smart and it works for my script. However, there is one issue with your solution: the function Exists() on the end statement deletes all rows where target_hosts have other specifications. It is possible that there are hosts that have more than one specification and than there is no row with null() specification for that host and these rows must be kept. Could you please give me one more hint?

Comment: @user3867873 I made a small correction to the `WHERE` clause for the last table - does that help?

Comment: You're genius, my friend! It makes no sense for me, but it works. Thank you very much!